# Version Conflicts Warnings in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sitecore

I get some conflict warnings when I try to run the solution from visual studio and I have no idea how to solve the following warnings:

`There was a conflict between "Sitecore.Kernel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "Sitecore.Kernel, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". (TaskId:65)
2>      "Sitecore.Kernel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was chosen because it was primary and "Sitecore.Kernel, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was not. (TaskId:65)
2>      References which depend on "Sitecore.Kernel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" [C:\ABC\XYZ\lib\Sitecore\Sitecore.Kernel.dll]. (TaskId:65)`

I have tried to solve this warning for several hours but still can't get a solution...

Comment: You have references to libraries that use SiteCore 6 ( probably meaning they are compile against it ) and libraries that use SiteCore 7. Track down the dependencies and have a look whether the library referencing the wrong version is available in a suitable version. From your error message it is not possible to tell you what reference creates the conflict

Comment: Are you pulling the SiteCore stuff from nuget? Try adding assembly redirects: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Nov/29/Updating-Assembly-Redirects-with-NuGet

Comment: Hi Sascha, thank you for your comments and I check my reference version from the project. All the references point to Sitecore.Kernel version 7.0.0.0. I didn't see any reference to version 6.0.0.0?

Comment: Hey mxmissile, I use other ways to download the siteCore and I also check the installed packages from nuget, no package named sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

I do know that visual studio 2015 community is available for individual developers for free. so if you were to use that you would have the latest visual studio and there shouldn't be any errors from the visual studio side of things.

[Visual Studio 2015 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x409&downloadrename=true)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think the problem may be caused by some coding or configuration issues from my project...

Comment: check your webconfig file to make sure that your referencing the right libraries and check some of your solution references.

Comment: Hey MMoore94, I check my web.config file and the assembly file is <assembly>/bin/Sitecore.Kernel.dll</assembly> And the version of sitecore.kernel.dll is 7.2.5408.0. I didn't find any reference to version 6.0.0.0...

Comment: is that the latest version of the kernel.dll?

Comment: also try going to (in visual studio on the menu bar) website -> add reference -> then looking through to see if you have a reference there that is creating conflicts. (i had that happen last week)

Comment: 7.2.5408 is the version I use for the project. The latest version for sitecore is 8.0 but I didn't upgrade to 8.0 yet.

Comment: have you tried just wiping that reference and then re-adding it. (gotta go through all the easy stuff first haha)

Comment: I tried to delete Sitecore.kernel.dll and add it again. There is still the same warning after rebuild the project...